# How to get IMEI, Serial No, MAC Address and Advertiser_id in cordova for iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want to fetch IMEI no, Serial no, MAC Address and Advertiser_id of a device through my Phonegap application. How can i achieve that? Any pulggin is available?

Comment: It is not possible to get the IMEI, serial or MAC address of an iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

You can not get any of the things you just named. If you need a unique string for each device, you can use:

```
let deviceID : String = (UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString)!
```